# First coefficient of a generating function

Tags: combinatorics, power-series, generating-functions

Can the first coefficient of a generating function not be $1$? I’m solving a combinatorics problem in which I have to multiply $4$ generating functions. I could find the sum of the first, but not of the other $3$. I started with:

$1+x^2+x^4+x^6 \dots = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$

I can’t find the sum of these other series though, since they don’ start with $1$:

$x+x^3+x^5+\dots$ (coefficients are the odd numbers)

$x^2+x^5+x^8+\dots$ (coefficients are each $2$ more than a multiple of $3$)

$x^3+x^7+x^{11}+\dots$ (coefficients are $3$ more than a multiple of $4$)

Any tips on finding the sums of these sequences and of other series in general?

Comment: try multiplying the expansion of $\frac 1{1-x^2}$ with $x$

Comment: Hıint:You can write them by taking them in the parentheses of $x$ such that $x(1+x^2+...)$ etc

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. As a side note, where do I find a guide on how to write using the appropriate notation and not x^2, for example?

Comment: Mathjax tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference